# The code refers to the Collection by its interface type (eg., Set) rather than by its implementation type

Tags: java, collections

I have seen mostly anycode always referring to the Collection by its interface type (for example, Set) rather than by its implementation type.

Below is the reason provided by the [Oracle's Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html),

> This is a strongly recommended programming practice because it gives you
>   the flexibility to change implementations merely by changing the constructor. 
>   If either of the variables used to store a collection or the parameters used 
>   to pass it around are declared to be of the Collection's implementation type 
>   rather than its interface type, all such variables and parameters must be 
>   changed in order to change its implementation type.

Furthermore down the line, the author provides there's no guarantee that the resulting program will work. If the program uses any ***nonstandard operations*** present in the original ***implementation type*** but ***not in the new one***, the program will fail. Referring to collections only by their interface prevents you from using any nonstandard operations.

What are the nonstandard operations that the author talks about?

Secondly, how come referring to collections only by their interface prevents us from using any nonstandard operations?

Kindly elaborate with the help of a Java code?

Comment: The example was on the same page where you've found it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html  They have used Set for this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One example for this is `LinkedList` which has a `getFirst()` and `getLast()` method. Using them seems convenient, but if the implementation changes to `ArrayList`, they are gone.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple advantages by initializing with interface for and instance.

```
List list = new Arraylist();
```

Now you are having list object which can be later on useful for any class which implement List interface.

But once you having `ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList()` you will loose such opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one pitfall you need to consider even while using interfaces.

Consider the following code:

```
public void sampleMethod(List<String> list) {
    list.add("baz");

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

We are using only standart operations defined by the interface, but if you check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), you will notice that `add()` operation is optional.

So, if you execute the following code

```
public void test() {
    List<String> sampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    sampleList.add("foo");

    try {
        sampleMethod(sampleList);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        sampleMethod(Collections.unmodifiableList(sampleList));
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        sampleMethod(Collections.singletonList("bar"));
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

you will get:

```
[foo, baz]
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1075)
    ...
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    ...
```

This is one example why your program can fail even if you use only standart operations.